# Store and retrieve debit and credit card details in Braintree

Tags: android, paypal, braintree

I am using `Braintree's v2 drop-in ui` android for payment and my backend server is in `node.js`. I have successfully implemented payment section but now I need to store the `card details` and deduct amount automatically from that stored `debit/credit card` or `paypal account`.

I am generating client token and store that token in my database. Using that token I am generating nonce. Then I am sending the nonce to backend server for `transaction.sale()`.

Here is the code snippet for payment section

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(braintreeClientToken)) {
    DropInRequest dropInRequest = new DropInRequest()
                    .clientToken(braintreeClientToken);
    startActivityForResult(dropInRequest.getIntent(this), REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

OnActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            DropInResult result = data.getParcelableExtra(DropInResult.EXTRA_DROP_IN_RESULT);
            PaymentMethodNonce paymentMethodNonce = result.getPaymentMethodNonce();
            String nonce = "";
            if (paymentMethodNonce != null)
                nonce = paymentMethodNonce.getNonce();
            // use the result to update your UI and send the payment method nonce to your server
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(nonce)) {
                NonceRequest obj = new NonceRequest("ANDROID", "1",
                            "DRIVER-SAVE-PAYMENT", "1", nonce);
                Call<NonceResponse> call = RestService.getInstance().restInterface.sendNonceToServer(userId, userToken, obj);
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<NonceResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<NonceResponse> call, Response<NonceResponse> response) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<NonceResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // the user canceled
        } else {
            // handle errors here, an exception may be available in
            Exception error = (Exception) data.getSerializableExtra(DropInActivity.EXTRA_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me the steps to store a `credit/debit card` or `paypal account` details and generate nonce from  that stored `payment-method`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/)</sub>

Most of what you want to accomplish will be changes on your server-side. If you want to store a card, you can either pass into the options parameter [storeInVaultOnSuccess](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/node#options.store_in_vault_on_success), which will save that card on success and create an associated customer with that card. Otherwise, you can also pass that nonce into a [PaymentMethod.Create](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create/node) call. If these calls are successful, a token will be created for those cards which you will then be able to reuse. Based on the fact you stated you wanted to "deduct amount automatically", I think you may want to setup a subscription using that token. For this, you'd need to create a [plan](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/plans), which is a template for your subscriptions in the control panel. Then you'd want to actually create the [subscription](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create/ruby) using the stored token that you've created. If you want these saved cards to show up in the Drop-in for a customer to select, you'll want to pass the [customer_id](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate/node#customer_id) into the ClientToken.generate call. This will allow the customer to select a stored card from their list and reuse in the Drop-in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer there is no recurring payment amount can be variable can you please clarify one doubt do I need to create a plan?

Comment: In order to create a subscription, you need to create a plan. When you create a plan, this is where you specify the amount.

Comment: There is no recurring payment. It is a cab booking app. There we want to deduct the amount from passenger from previously save payment method. For that reason the amount will be variable and I can't apply subscription like monthly yearly quarterly daily

Comment: Therefore, it seems like you just want the ability to reuse vaulted cards. In this case, all you need to do is same as above, you'll just adjust the amount parameter in the transaction.sale() call.

Comment: I am using custom ui that's why `DropInResult.fetchDropInResult` is not working so how can I show stored card info in ui. Will I create a new thread or you can give a solution here?

Comment: That's correct, you shouldn't use DropiInResult.fetchDropInResult if you plan on using custom UI. In order for you to shored stored card info without the Drop-in this would require custom logic where you fetch the cards server-side based on the customer in order to show it client-side. This is not a method that Braintree provides outside of the Drop-in.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out and implemented custom logic from server side thanks for your kind help.

Comment: can you please clarify one doubt. Is real debit/credit card works in sandbox mode?

Comment: no, you should not be using real cards in sandbox. only the  testing cards: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/credit-cards/testing-go-live/